# Swipe and expand view Android

Tags: android, android-layout, user-experience

Good evening everyone,

I've been struggling to find out a way to do this. I have an activity. In this activity I have a "top menu", and a fragment holding a listview. The goal is for the top menu to be expanded either when the setting button is pressed, or the down arrow is swiped:
[image]
[image]

Currently, I'm just adjusting the height and properties of the top menu view according to if it's expanded or not. I'm pretty sure this is not the proper way to implement this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I have faced similar problem with swiping elements. You can use OnTouchListener and GestureDetector to detect dragging

I wrote simple android library for this problem, it has also functions to expand view on your setting button press.

[swiping library](https://github.com/colorgreen/swipe-touch-listener)

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick reply! It seems exactly like what i need. I'll itry to implement it using yout lib and report back to you as soon as I can